# ByteBuddy - Modify load class's default value

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm trying to change the return value of a method of an already loaded class.

From ByteBuddy's documentation (http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) this seems possible using the Java agent, as long as I don't add any field/method.

My code is the following:

```
ByteBuddyAgent.install();

new ByteBuddy()
        .redefine(StuffImpl.class)
        .method(returns(Result.class))
        .intercept(FixedValue.value(new Result("intercepted")))
        .make()
        .load(StuffImpl.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
```

The thing is, I'm not adding any method. Where does Byte Buddy add a field or method in the above code?

**EDIT:**

```
public class StuffImpl {

    public Result validate() {
        return new Result("original");
    }
}

public class Result {

    private String result;

    public Result(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a delegation to a fixed value `new Result("intercepted")` that Byte Buddy needs to store somewhere. The `FixedValue` implementation creates a static field for you such that the generated method can read your value from it. You can work arround this in different ways by avoiding `FixedValue`, for example:

1. Delegate to another class that holds the value in a field (retains reference identity).

   ```
   MethodDelegation.to(Holder.class);
   class Holder {
     static Result result = new Result("intercepted");
     static Result intercept() { return result; }
   }
   ```

   This is the most universal approach, you can of course return `new Result("intercepted")` directly from the method.
2. Create the instance dynamically:

   ```
   MethodCall.construct(Result.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class))
             .with("intercepted");
   ```

   In this case, the `"intercepted"` string does not need to be stored in a field because it can be referenced in the class's constant pool (the same goes for primitive values).

---

<s>Your `StuffImpl` probably defines a static initializer. This initializer is factored out by Byte Buddy into a `private` method such that it can add additional statements to it.</s>

You can disable this behaviour by setting:

```
new ByteBuddy().with(Implementation.Context.Disabled.Factory.INSTANCE);
```

This should really be in the docs and I will add it for the next release.